# Google Charts Timeline change bar height with react-google-charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I have this google chart timeline (using react-google-charts).

```
 <Chart
   chartType="Timeline"
   data={data}
   width="100%"
   options={{
            allowHtml: true
            bar: { groupWidth: 10 },
          }}
  />
```

I tried adding `bar: { groupWidth: 10 }` and its working on the normal bar chart but not on the timeline.

Try for example this jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c5hyknfr/2/

Doesnt work for the timeline. Any other way to do that?

EDIT: Added a bounty, in case someone knows also any workaround with CSS and/or using classes. Hacky solutions approved.

Comment: there are no options for changing bar height in the timeline chart...

Comment: do you know if there is a workaround? maybe using CSS classes? and manually adding the CSS with !important?

Comment: you can try css, or modifying the chart's svg manually, on the chart's ready event

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the font size for the bar's labels. This will also increase the bar's height. You need to add the `barLabelStyle.fontSize`-property in the options-object:

```js
var options = {
  timeline: {
    groupByRowLabel: true,
    showRowLabels: true,
    rowLabelStyle: {
      fontName: 'Helvetica',
      fontSize: 9,
      color: '#000000'
    },
    barLabelStyle: {
      fontSize: 30
    }
  },
  'width': 1100,
  'height': 2200,
  'chartArea': {
    width: '80%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
    height: '80%'
  },
  'backgroundColor': '#ffd',

  'view': {
    'columns': [0, 1, 4, 5]
  }
};
```

Then you could adjust your CSS to decrease the font-size again, but your bars will remain bigger. Please note that the labels of the bars aren't correctly centered anymore. That's why you need to transform the position, so the labels are centered again:

```css
rect + text {
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
```

With the values from the example it will look like this:

[image]